# Uploading File to Django Using Ajax File is always None

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

I wrote a script that POST a file to a django view for processing with ajax. However, I can't seem to get the file to pass as a file. It just outputs as none in Django.

Django View - This view is not finished just trying to make sure I have the file, it fails at chunks now because there is no file, as you can see im printing username and file, and the username prints but the file is none.

```
def upload_profilepic(request):
    print request.POST
    id = request.POST['username']
    f = request.FILES.get('file')
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    print f, username

    path = 'C:\Users\Administraor\workspace\ChompProject\ChompMe\static\images\user_images%s' % id    
    destination = open(path, 'wb+')
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()
```

Ajax Function

```
                $("#uppropic").click(function() {
                        var files = $('#profile_pic').val();
                        console.log(files);   
                        var username = '{{user.username}}'; 

                        $.ajax({
                                url : "/profilepic/",
                                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
                                type: 'POST',
                                url : '/profilepic/',
                                enctype: "multipart/form-data",
                                data  : {
                                        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
                                        file: $('#profile_pic').val(),
                                        username: username,
                                },
                                        success : function(data) {
                                            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = (data['message']);
                                        },
                                        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                                            console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
                                            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = " Request Failed.";
                                        }

                        });
                        return false;  
                });
```

Form

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
{% if is_user_profile %}        

<div id='profile_pics'>         
        <form method='POST' enctype=multipart/form-data id='profile_pic_form'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type='file' id='profile_pic'>
        <button id='uppropic'> Upload Profile Pic</button>
        {% for user in user_data %}
        <input type='hidden' id='username' value='{{user.username}}'>
        {%endfor%}
        </form>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{%endif%}
```

So I changed to using an html iframe instead,

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
    <link href='{% static "css/bootstrap.css" %}' rel="stylesheet"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src= '{% static "js/bootstrap.js" %}'></script>
 </head>

<body>
<div>
<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>  
{% csrf_token %}

<div style="width:100%;background:#217fbc;color:#fff;padding:7px;">
<img src='{% static "images/icons/chomp.png" %}'><p style='float:right;margin-top:5px;'> Upload Pic</p>
</div>

<div style="width:100%;background:#fff;color:#352f29;padding:15px;">

<input type='file' name='file'>

</div>

<div style='width:100%;background:#4a525f;color:#FFF;padding:7px;height:50px;'>
<p style='float:right;'><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value='Upload'></p>
</div>  

</form>
</div>

</body>
```

Here Is my views.py file the form calls. I get a method error

> [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename:
>   'C:\Users\Administraor\workspace\ChompProject\ChompMe\static\images\user_images'

As you can see the file is being passed and the var f is being set to the file. However, I'm not sure what the problem is because thats how you open a file for writing in python.    f

```
@login_required  
@csrf_protect       
def upload_profilepic(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.FILES.get('file')
        username = request.user
        print f, username

        path = 'C:\Users\Administraor\workspace\ChompProject\ChompMe\static\images\user_images%s' % id    
        destination = open(path, 'wb')
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
        destination.close()

    context = {'user': request.user,
                }

    return render_to_response('profile_pic.html',context ,  RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: You cannot upload a file through ajax. You have to use the form to POST the files and data.

Comment: so ill have to do it in an iframe then to not refresh the page?

Comment: ya, iframe will be a good option.

Comment: @Biswas I added some info can you take a look?

Comment: what did you get? always none ?